# How to run an app without main in Rust built with Bare ARM

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have the following Rust program:

```
//app.rs
#![no_main]
#![no_std]

use core::panic::PanicInfo;

#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_panic: &PanicInfo<'_>) -> ! {
    loop {}
}
```

built by using

```
rustc --target armv7a-none-eabi app.rs
```

NOTE: target `armv7a-none-eabi` does not allow to have `fn main`.

It produces an application `app` and I ran in a Bare ARM platform:

```
# chmod +x app
# ls -l app
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           572 Dec  6  2022 app
# file app
app_rust: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
# ./app
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you want to use something like the [`#[entry]` attribute from the `cortex-m-rt` crate](https://docs.rs/cortex-m-rt/latest/cortex_m_rt/attr.entry.html)

```
use cortex_m_rt::entry;

#[entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    loop {
        /* .. */
    }
}
```

You will, of course, need to add the crate as a dependency first:

```bash
cargo add cortex-m-rt
```

Comment: ```error[E0432]: unresolved import `cortex_m`
 --> main.rs:3:5```

Comment: You will need to add the crate to your dependencies.

Comment: What is the *crate*?

Comment: Do you not see the link in my answer? https://docs.rs/cortex-m-rt/

Comment: You might want to read the [Embedded Rust Book](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/book/)

Comment: ```# ./app```
```Segmentation fault (core dumped)```

Comment: back to sq one which is core dumpd

Comment: There is quite a bit of setup involved. Did you add `memory.x` and a linker script as the crate documentation requires?

Comment: It also looks like you're trying to run it locally on your own computer? What CPU does your computer have?

Comment: The program ```app``` built on my local linux/windows box with Rust/Cargo and it runs on ```Linux ..... armv7l GNU/Linux``` which is another device

Comment: I don't think we need to set up all those thing such as memory.x, I also refer to this link https://blog.japaric.io/quickstart/

Comment: You do need those things. They're explicitly mentioned in the article you linked.

Comment: It also appears you're trying to use this an as executable. I'm not sure if this form is compatible with that. Is there a reason you're not using `armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabi` instead?

Comment: Tried ````armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabi``` and get  ```error: linker `armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc` not found```. open issue https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/105406 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74709742/cargo-rust-build-time-error-with-target-armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabi

Comment: Looks like not every target has its own linker ?!